# Облачные технологии

Tags: облако, сервисы

Добро всем дня. Я занимаюсь тем, что пишу различные программы под десктоп и знаете... что то меня зае**ло это, надоело что ли. Стал подумывать о смене курса и тут выходов не так уж и много: мобильные приложения, веб и облачные технологии. С первыми двумя все и так понятно, а вот про третий путь развития мне очень интересно услышать от людей, которые в этом разбираются и от тех, кто знаете всю "кухню" разработки облачных сервисов. Что, как, почему и для чего?

P.S. Почему я "копаю" именно в направление облачный сервисов? Ответ прост как пять копеек, это направление захватывает все больше и больше умов, это перспективно, как мне кажется. Думаю будущее именно за ними.

Comment: Комментарий к топику напишу такой, ТС слышал звон - но не знает где он!

Comment: можно написать любой сайт, который будет предоставлять ту или иную услугу(вставку и сохранение скриншотов по Prt Scr и ctrl+v, например) и назвать это SaaS, т.к. фактически пользователи не устанавливают ваше ПО на свои компы, а пользуются услугой "на облаке"

Comment: @Palmervan, ну в принципе оно так и есть, и я этого не скрываю. Для того и существуют различные сайты типа этого, форумы итп.
Даже поставлю вам +

Comment: @drdaeman, перемести комментарий в ветку ответов, отмечу, что ответ дан.

Comment: @Jetu: Сделано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Облако» это такой баззворд. К программированию отношение имеет примерно такое же, как термин «океан» к работе сантехника.

Облачные технологии полезны менеджерам, которые должны с умным видом успешно продавать даже снег эскимосам. Говорит такой «облако, хайлоад, мобильность!» и все понимают — да, перспективно, инновационно.

Все это «облако», по факту — пачка обычных VPSок и немножко отказоустойчивых систем (как правило, на уровне hot spares и репликации). Это все админское, а не кодерское. И капелька распределенных вычислений (где-то, обычно, не шибко глубже «разобъем задачу на куски-узлы.»)